# Access TextViews in an Activity that isn't started

Tags: android

I have a settings button, which launches SettingsMenu.class. In there, there's a button that will reset your stats and after they reset I need the TextViews to refresh. But they are in an activity, InventoryMenu.class, that hasn't been started yet.

I'm not sure how I would work around this, I'm going to try to see if I can maybe start InventoryMenu.class after the reset button is pressed so I don't get a NullPointerException. But the problem with starting the InventoryMenu.class is that it opens the inventory

Refreshing the TextView in SettingsMenu.class -

```
InventoryMenu inv = new InventoryMenu();
TextView t1 = inv.t1;
t1.setText("");
```

Getting the TextView in InventoryMenu.class, which is not started yet -

```
public TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inventorySlot1);
```

Comment: post your full source in the Question this way we can't understand more ?

Comment: This is the code in SettingsMenu.class after the button is pressed -
    InventoryMenu inv = new InventoryMenu();
    TextView t1 = inv.t1;

Comment: The NullPointerException is thrown on this line, which is in the Activity that was not started yet - public TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inventorySlot1);

Comment: Use static keyword for your textview and you can access that textview in other activity (But personally I wont suggest you to use static)

Comment: @RakshitNawani If you wouldn't suggest it, then why comment a suggestion?

Comment: @CitricThunder It sounds like you can just `finish()` the `InventoryMenu` when you start `SettingsMenu`... The TextViews will be cleared then, you don't need to access them elsewhere.

Comment: @cricket_007 : my bad but I think it will do the trick for him

Comment: @cricket_007 `InventoryMenu` is never started

Comment: I don't understand. Please post your full code, not these small snippets

Comment: If the activity isn't started, why are you trying to access the TextViews? You don't need to "reset" them, because they were never changed. Activity's should cross-reference their Views. It sounds like you need some sort of storage for an Inventory like a SQLite table to insert/update/reset your data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing Android `Context` (`getApplicationContext()`) to `SettingsMenu` class as parameter and need to inflate corresponding the required layout in which all your text views would be available to access?

Only then can we load all `TextView` and `setText` or reset whatever actions you want to perform on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to access something in an activity that has not been started. Also, you should NEVER create an activity by calling its constructor like this:

```
new InventoryMenu()
```

What you should do is the other way round. You should access the settings in the `InventoryMenu` activity's `onCreate`.

But first, you should put the new set of settings that the user has set in some place, so that `InventoryMenu` can access it later. I would recommend `SharedPreferences`.

To put the statsReset settings into shared preferences:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    .edit().putBoolean("statsReset", someBoolean).apply();
```

where `someBoolean` should be replaced with the actual value that the user selected.

Now in `InventoryMenu`, check if `statsReset` is true and do corresponding things:

```
boolean statsReset = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    .getBoolean("statsReset", false);

if (statsReset) {
    // change the text of the text view or whatever
} else {
    // do other stuff
}
```

where `false` is the default value.